# How to choose the not previously used links by an agent

Tags: netlogo

I have `breed [walkers walker]` which walk roads in a road map represented by links in Netlogo.
The `links-own [ guiri-ids ]` which I intend to be an `turtle-set` of walkers that have already walked for the link.
I would like to use this `guiri-ids`  to select, from the set of possible next links, which I call `nextlinks`, the links that the walker has not been walked before (the new ones). 
If all possible links have been walked before then choose one of them.

How could obtain the set of next links which `guiri-ids` set does not contain myself (the walker) ?.

I am trying this line

```
let new-nextlinks nextlinks with [ guiri-ids != myself ]
```

but the keeps taking old paths.

Thank your very much for your help

Comment: Test membership instead of equality:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member

Comment: I do not know how to use `member?`to get the agentset. For example, `let new-nextlinks nextlinks with [ not member? myself guiri-ids ]`does not work. Can you tell me something else? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
breed [walkers walker]
links-own [ guiri-ids ]

to test
  ca
  crt 25 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask turtles [
    create-link-with one-of other turtles
  ]
  create-walkers 10
  ask links [set guiri-ids n-of 3 walkers]
  ask walkers [walk]
end

to walk
  let _next one-of links with [not member? myself guiri-ids]
  ifelse (_next != nobody) [
    ask _next [set guiri-ids (turtle-set myself guiri-ids)]
  ] [
    ;do whatever you wish in this case
  ]
end
```